# Ember.js redirect to first item error

Tags: ember.js

I have a list of tickets. When I go to route "tickets" I display a list of them. I want the first item to be automatically selected. I found the solution here on stackoverflow, but it doesn't work for me. The code is:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('tickets', function() {
        this.resource('ticket', { path: ':ticket_id' });
    });
    this.resource('feedback');
});

App.TicketsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Ticket.find();
    }, 
    redirect: function() {
        var ticket = this.modelFor('tickets').get('firstObject');
        this.transitionTo('ticket', ticket);
    }
});
```

When I first time visit tickets route it selects the first item. But then I go to another route and return to tickets. After that I get next error:

```
WARNING: The immediate parent route ('a') did not render into the main outlet and the    default 'into' option ('p') may not be expected
```

And the markup becomes wrong, it doesn't display list of items (only detailed info about first ticket). I don't understand the error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: would you mind posting your router code?

Answer (score 1):

The warning is because the template that was rendering did not find an outlet in it's parent. I'm guessing maybe you have a `ticket.hbs` template but no `tickets.hbs`? Ideally it should be something like:

```
// in tickets.hbs
{{#each ticket in tickets}}
  //ticket link
{{/each}}
{{outlet}}

// tickets/index.hbs
Please select a ticket from the list

// in ticket.hbs
// ticket details
```

See https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1916#issuecomment-13669980 for an explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much for this comment. I had been looking all day trying to figure out similar error message in my app. Nice clear answer.